# Unsupervised classification in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, classification, qgis-2.6

I was trying to learn unsupervised classification in QGIS 2.6 following the tutorial video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mI80eENtWSE 
When trying myself, clicked **Run** during the process it shows the message, "Input layer ag020522_DPAC has more than one band. Multiband layers are not supported by SAGA". But it seems like during the tutorial the image used was Multiband layers. Am I right? Do I need to process the data anyhow first? I downloaded the data from this link: https://github.com/FOSS4GAcademy/GST101FOSS4GLabs.

Comment: It seems like you didn't make any effort to search it in the internet. But you can use those links: http://www.igismap.com/image-classification-in-qgis-supervised-and-unsupervised-classification/ , http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Unsupervised_classification_(Tutorial) , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcdfXCAnpp4

Answer (score 5):

I found this at the QGIS 2.2 documentation at "[Limitation for multi-band layers](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html)"

Obviously there is a limitation of multi band layers, what means that they are not supported. As a work around one can extract every single band with the raster calculator  `Raster > Raster Calculator`.

[image]

Save each raster-band as a single tif-file an load it in the QGIS-project.Now the SAGA Cluster analysis is performable by selecting those three rasters in the `Multi selction window`.

[image]